# jQuery Flot chart: "Scroll" months

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, flot

I've got a chart in jQuery Flot with Data for each month, i.e. the x-axis represents the days of one month. For most easy usage, I just represent a similar one to you, just look at the fifth from the top (the one in the red box):

http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic_admin/charts.html

The code for this type of graph looks like this:

```
function chart2() {
    function randValue() {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 40 - 20))) + 20;
    }
    var pageviews = [
        [1, randValue()],
        [2, randValue()],
        [3, 2 + randValue()],
        [4, 3 + randValue()],
        [5, 5 + randValue()],
        [6, 10 + randValue()],
        [7, 15 + randValue()],
        [8, 20 + randValue()],
        [9, 25 + randValue()],
        [10, 30 + randValue()],
        [11, 35 + randValue()],
        [12, 25 + randValue()],
        [13, 15 + randValue()],
        [14, 20 + randValue()],
        [15, 45 + randValue()],
        [16, 50 + randValue()],
        [17, 65 + randValue()],
        [18, 70 + randValue()],
        [19, 85 + randValue()],
        [20, 80 + randValue()],
        [21, 75 + randValue()],
        [22, 80 + randValue()],
        [23, 75 + randValue()],
        [24, 70 + randValue()],
        [25, 65 + randValue()],
        [26, 75 + randValue()],
        [27, 80 + randValue()],
        [28, 85 + randValue()],
        [29, 90 + randValue()],
        [30, 95 + randValue()]
    ];
    var visitors = [
        [1, randValue() - 5],
        [2, randValue() - 5],
        [3, randValue() - 5],
        [4, 6 + randValue()],
        [5, 5 + randValue()],
        [6, 20 + randValue()],
        [7, 25 + randValue()],
        [8, 36 + randValue()],
        [9, 26 + randValue()],
        [10, 38 + randValue()],
        [11, 39 + randValue()],
        [12, 50 + randValue()],
        [13, 51 + randValue()],
        [14, 12 + randValue()],
        [15, 13 + randValue()],
        [16, 14 + randValue()],
        [17, 15 + randValue()],
        [18, 15 + randValue()],
        [19, 16 + randValue()],
        [20, 17 + randValue()],
        [21, 18 + randValue()],
        [22, 19 + randValue()],
        [23, 20 + randValue()],
        [24, 21 + randValue()],
        [25, 14 + randValue()],
        [26, 24 + randValue()],
        [27, 25 + randValue()],
        [28, 26 + randValue()],
        [29, 27 + randValue()],
        [30, 31 + randValue()]
    ];

    var plot = $.plot($("#chart_2"), [{
                data: pageviews,
                label: "Unique Visits",
                lines: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                },
                shadowSize: 0

            }, {
                data: visitors,
                label: "Page Views",
                lines: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            }
        ], {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                                opacity: 0.05
                            }, {
                                opacity: 0.01
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                points: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 3,
                    lineWidth: 1
                },
                shadowSize: 2
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                tickColor: "#eee",
                borderColor: "#eee",
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            colors: ["#d12610", "#37b7f3", "#52e136"],
            xaxis: {
                ticks: 11,
                tickDecimals: 0,
                tickColor: "#eee",
            },
            yaxis: {
                ticks: 11,
                tickDecimals: 0,
                tickColor: "#eee",
            }
        });


    function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 15,
                border: '1px solid #333',
                padding: '4px',
                color: '#fff',
                'border-radius': '3px',
                'background-color': '#333',
                opacity: 0.80
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
    }

    var previousPoint = null;
    $("#chart_2").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
        $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();
                var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y);
            }
        } else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

That means I want to display buttons to "scroll" though the months so that I can view the data for previous and/or next month as well...

Can that be done with Flot!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially the same as this example: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/index.html

You plot all your data, then tie the buttons to the xaxis min and max to adjust the window that is visible.

Comment: Thanks very nice, didn't know that example. Its quite nice. Possible to pan/drag the graph to adjust the current month instead of displaying and adjusting buttons to change the months!?

Comment: @tim Take a look at the other examples.